# for which values of x this function is discontinuous?

Tags: calculus, continuity

[image: discontinuous function]

I've only found x is discontinuous when = -2 and -3, but i'm no pretty sure if is the same for x<-3

Comment: Surely $-2$ and $-3$; also $2$ (but not $4$, where the function is not defined).

Comment: ... unless the value for $x=4$ happens to be a point that is not shown, being $> 6$ or $< -6$.

Comment: but if at x=4 is not defined, then is discontinuous isn't it?

Comment: @nutshell_A you cannot talk about discontinuity where the function is not defined

Comment: @gt6989b ok thanks, I had a bit of confusion with that part...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\lim_{x\to -3,x<-3}f(x)=f(-3^-)=3$$
$$f(-3^+)=-1=f(-3)$$

thus $f$ is continuous on the right of $-3$ and discontinuous on the left.

$$f(2)=4$$
$$f(2^-)=f(2^+)=2\ne f(2)$$

$f$ is discontinuous at $x=2$.